# Calculate the difference between timestamp on google cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that will run daily to check the age of every post, so how I can get the difference (in seconds) between the timestamp that I have stored in Firestore (stored as timestamp type) and the current timestamp.

```
exports.dailyCheckPost = functions.runWith(runtimeOptions).pubsub.schedule("28 15 * * *").timeZone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur').onRun(async () => {

    console.log("Function Running!")

    const snapshot = await firestore.collection("post").where("isPublished","==",true).get();

    snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {

        const data = doc.data()

        var difference = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now() - data.createdAt

        firestore.collection("users").doc(doc.id).set({
            age : difference
        },
        {
            merge: true
        })
    })

});
```

Comment: Is there a requirement to calculate this age and store it in the document? As soon as you write that data, wouldn't it be immediately outdated and wrong? Could this not be computed by the clients of your projects as needed?

Comment: no requirement at all sir, all I need is just to automatically change the viewing status of the post from true to false once it reaches sometimes, let's say more than 30 days or so, that is why i need to have the age of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...

```
var difference = new Date().valueOf() - data.createdAt.toDate().valueOf();
```

If you want to know the google real time...

```
admin.firestore().collection("time").doc("timeDoc").update({
  updateAt:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}

const query = admin.firestore().collection("time").doc("timeDoc").get();
var difference = query.data().createAt.toDate().valueOf() - data.createdAt.toDate().valueOf();
```

However, the difference(ms) still exist the inaccuracy because the internet delay...

But... the admin object... it seems it is server code, and we usually use `local time - createAt`. Because our server always connects to internet, and rarely delays.